# pragmatically scroll UIScrollView upon shake gesture

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, shake, gestures

HI,

I have a view that has three UIScrollViews on the screen. I want to randomly scroll the UIScrollViews to different positions whenever a user shakes the iPhone, but I am unable to get it done.

I have implemented the following in my ViewController class to detect and handle the shake gesture, the 3 UIScrollViews also belong to the same class. The shake gesture is detected, but the UIScrollViews do not change. What am I doing Wrong??

i have tried both motionBegan and motionEnded.

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
  int randomTag = arc4random() % [dirContents count];

  CGRect nextImageView = [[scrollView1 viewWithTag:2] frame];
  [scrollView1 scrollRectToVisible:nextImageView animated:YES];

  randomTag = arc4random() % [dirContents count];
  nextImageView = [[scrollView2 viewWithTag:4] frame];
  [scrollView2 scrollRectToVisible:nextImageView animated:YES];

  randomTag = arc4random() % [dirContents count];
  nextImageView = [[scrollView3 viewWithTag:4] frame];
  [scrollView3 scrollRectToVisible:nextImageView animated:YES];
  NSLog(@"Shake Detected End");
    }
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `SetContentOffset` instead of `scrollRectToVisible` yet?

if the images in your tableView are of equal height the offset per "Element" is always the same.

```
[scrollView3 setContentOffset:yourRandomOffsetInPixels animated:YES];
```

maybe this works.
also consider, that **The Problem might be that your shake-detection Method runs on a separate Thread** this would mean that you have to call your `motionEnded` Method on the mainthread like so:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(motionEnded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I havent tried using the SetContentOffset because everwhere else i have used scrollRectToVisible. Maybe I might give it a try.

Where am i supposed to use this line exactly?? I do not understand.
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(motionEnded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: scrollRectToVisible is a tricky bast. If it considers the defined rectangle to be visible, it'll ignore the request, and I've found it not doing what I wanted on a number of occasions. setContentOffset normally fixed it.

Comment: Yes it worked with SetContentOffset. Thank you samsam and mtc06!
Although I would have loved for it to work with scrollRectVisible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your nextImageView variable to see if it was correct ?

Further more if you are trying will have the motion of a slot machine, I would recommend you to use UITableView instead of doing it by yourself with scrollView

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make it like a slot machine, which can be randomized upon shake and also the individual slots can be changed by dragging.

Is this doable with a table view?? What if I want to load images in the table view?

Comment: You can load anything in your TableView. In Each TableViewCell, you can add any view to the contentView...
But it will be easier to make scroll a TableView to a specific row number, it will calculate by itself it's position.

Answer (score 0):

Just one quick question. In your example code, you generate a random tag:

```
randomTag = arc4random() % [dirContents count];
```

but then you use a specific tag value (4 in this case)? I assume it still doesn't work when you use the randomTag value? and that you were just doing some testing?

```
 nextImageView = [[scrollView2 viewWithTag:4] frame];
```

Comment: yes, that was just some testing to see if there was a problem with the random variable.